# Search bar that can change language

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript so I don't know if this is even possible. I have a searchbar with an autocomplete function and I also have a few buttons that can change my websites language:

```js
//searchbar//
let availableKeywords = [
  'example1',
  'exapmle2',
  'example3'
];

const resultsBox = document.querySelector(".result-box");
const inputBox = document.getElementById("query");

inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
  let result = [];
  let input = inputBox.value;
  if(input.length){
    result = availableKeywords.filter((keyword)=>{
      return keyword.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase());
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
  display(result);

  if(!result.length){
    resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
  }
}

function display(result){
  const content = result.map((list)=>{
    return "<li onclick=selectInput(this)>" + list + "</li>";
  });

  resultsBox.innerHTML = "<ul>" + content.join('') + "</ul>";
}

function selectInput(list){
  inputBox.value = list.innerHTML;
  resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
}

//buttons//
const langEl = document.querySelector(".langWrap");

link.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    langEl.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
    el.classList.add("active");
});
```

I was wondering if it was possible that the content of availableKeywords could change language depending on which language button is active?

Comment: Can you paste your html code as well ?

Comment: @abhinav3414 in my answer I have produced some HTML that's compatible with this code, maybe you can use that as your point of departure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. First of all, convert `availableKeywords` from array into an object whose keys are the language names and the values associated to these names are the arrays of searchable keywords.

Second, make sure you manage the language changes and store the current language somewhere, I used `chosenLanguage` for that purpose.

Third, make sure that the `search` `function` is defined separately from the event and assign the event to this function so you can reuse it on language choice as well.

Fourth, upon search, refer to the array unlocked by the chosen language name (make sure your language names in the lis are compatible with the language names used in your object as keys)

Finally, make sure that your language choosing event is properly choosing the language and executing the search.

```js
//searchbar//
let availableKeywords = {
  en: [
      'biropen',
      'piglet',
      'piggyback',
      'bullet of the gun',
      'chewing gum'
  ],
  hu: [
      'golyóstoll',
      'kismalac',
      'hobby malacoglás',
      'puskagolyó',
      'rágógumi'
  ],
};

let chosenLanguage = 'en';

const resultsBox = document.querySelector(".result-box");
const inputBox = document.getElementById("query");

function search(){
  let result = [];
  let input = inputBox.value;
  if(input.length){
    result = availableKeywords[chosenLanguage].filter((keyword)=>{
      return keyword.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase());
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
  display(result);

  if(!result.length){
    resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
  }
}

inputBox.onkeyup = search;

function display(result){
  const content = result.map((list)=>{
    return "<li onclick=selectInput(this)>" + list + "</li>";
  });

  resultsBox.innerHTML = "<ul>" + content.join('') + "</ul>";
}

function selectInput(list){
  inputBox.value = list.innerHTML;
  resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
}

//buttons//
const langEl = [...document.querySelectorAll(".langWrap")];

langEl.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    langEl.map(item => item.classList.contains("active") ? item.classList.remove("active") : false);
    el.classList.add("active");
    chosenLanguage = el.innerText;
    search();
  });
});
```

```css
.langWrap.active {
    background-color: green;
}

.langWrap {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
}

ul#lang {
    display: contents;
}

ul#lang li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="lang">
    <li><span class="langWrap active">en</span></li>
    <li><span class="langWrap">hu</span></li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="query" placeholder="type your search here">
<div class="result-box"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, i tried your code but it doesn't work for me?

Comment: @Pascal please define "doesn't work". Have you tried running the snippet here inside the answer with an Expanded snippet? Did it work? If not, how did you try it and how did the failure manifest?

Comment: @Pascal search for the words defined, namely `let availableKeywords = {
  en: [
      'biropen',
      'piglet',
      'piggyback',
      'bullet of the gun',
      'chewing gum'
  ],
  hu: [
      'golyóstoll',
      'kismalac',
      'hobby malacoglás',
      'puskagolyó',
      'rágógumi'
  ],
};` with the appropriate language chosen.

Comment: i probably made a typo somewhere bcs its working now. Thanks!

Comment: @Pascal happy to help! If this answer solved the issue, you may consider accepting it as the correct answer.